Would it be mathematically rigorous to define: $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\frac{cx}{||x||} \mapsto c$?
I am wondering whether it would be mathematically rigorous to define: $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with:
$$\frac{cx}{||x||} \mapsto c$$
I feel like it's somewhat of a cheat (i.e. that the left-hand-side should be some general $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$), but on the other hand it feels obvious that there is such a parameterization and therefore that this would be acceptable.

First of all, your function is undefined at $x=0$.
Other than that, it is a perfectly valid (even if a bit needlessly complicated) definition.
In fact, it is quite common to define functions this way: prove that all elements in the domain admit a certain unique decomposition, and use it to define a function.
For example, any complex number can be uniquely represented as $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi)$, so we can define a function $g(z)=\theta$, bypassing an explicit formula for $g$ in terms of $z=x+iy$.
In your case though, the function can be alternatively defined as $f(x)=\|x\|$.
